# Como fechar o console da aplicação?

Tags: c++, qt

Eu executo esse programa com o executável, mas falta fechar o console que fica aberto após executar, como fazer isso?

[image: Captura de Tela]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5vHQT.png

Comment: Mas a tela não é fechada automaticamente.

Comment: Poste seu código do `Main()`

Comment: Nas definições de execução tens a opção `run in terminal` marcada? Se sim, vai sempre ser chamada a consola e o windows espera que o utilizador a feche...

Comment: Valeu galera!Basicamente o que eu queria fazer era abrir o spotify com um comando(A minha placa de video não renderiza ele, por isso esse comando), e não mostrar o prompt de comando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme mencionado pelo usuário Zuul:

Vai em Projects > Run e desmarca a opção "Run in Terminal"

[image: Run in terminal]

Comment: Muito obrigado!